# Change href onclick with multiple variables

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know very little about js so please be gentle.

I'm using the below code which was originally used to swap classes. I thought it would be as simple as changing `.className` to `.href` but I was wrong.

My problem is that it works once and then stops.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#click').click(function () {
    $('#url').each(function(){
      var classes = ['/1','/2','/3','/4'];
      this.href = classes[($.inArray(this.href, classes)+1)%classes.length];
    });
  });
});
```

**EDIT:**
Here is the html I'm using:

```
<a id="url" href="/0">hello</a>
```

My goal is to switch /0 with /1 then /2 and so on with each onclick.

Comment: Use - $(this).attr() method to change the href

Comment: It is stopping after doing it once because the id has to be unique. You need to apply the code to each link using a class or other selector. If your links are all the same id - then that will need to be changed as well.

Comment: Steve Jobs! Glad to have you back! So basically you are trying to change the class of an element from ```className``` to ```href```??

Comment: _"My problem is that it works once and then stops."_ What do you mean? Why do you call `.each()` on an element having an `#id`? The result should only occur once, unless there are duplicate `id`s in `document` having `id` `url`? Can you include `html` at Question? What is expected result?

Comment: @gavgrif do you mean to change the #url to .url?

Comment: _"My goal is to switch /0 with /1 then /2 and so on with each onclick"_ What should occur when `/4` is set and `#click` is clicked? Should `/1` be set?

Comment: @guest271314 Yes, exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.attr()`, set a varible to `-1`. At `click` event handler increment variable until variable reaches `classes.length`, then reset variable to `0`, without utilizing [`Remainder`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder_()) operator.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var classes = ['/1','/2','/3','/4'];
  var i = -1;
  var url = $("#url");
  $('#click').click(function () {
    i = (++i < classes.length) ? i : 0;
    url.attr("href", classes[i]);
    console.log(url.attr("href"));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<button id="click">click</button>
<a id="url" href="/0">hello</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

This fails because the protocol `file://` or `http://` is silently added the the `href` value.

So change this:

```
$.inArray(this.href, classes)
```

to:

```
$.inArray(this.href.replace(/^.*?\/\//, ''), classes)
```

... which removes the protocol from the string before looking it up in your array.